# Does ebay API allows to create a listing draft?

Tags: ebay-api

I would like to create a listing ebay draft as it is possible to do manually using this flow:

1. Go to the new listing sell creation page
2. Choose category id
3. Put some random data (title, description, etc.)
4. Close tab

You will see now unfinished draft, when you go to the new listing sell creation page. 
Can I do the same thing using eBay api?

The reason of it is that I don't want to implement all functionality of addItem, currently.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I can confirm eBay does provide the API to create listing draft, though it's in beta at the moment.

```
POST - /item_draft/
```

Official doc is [here](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/listing/resources/item_draft/methods/createItemDraft)

Comment: Link is out of date. When you find correct page, please also copy the relevant content to your answer

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this cannot be done, since there are some pretty strict constraints around using the addItem API call, and eBay will throw an error if you don't complete the all the required fields.  The required fields of addItem are numerous enough that if you could populate these fields, then you are already 90% of the way to completing your listing anyways.

If you are using Selling Manager Pro, you can create product templates which may be a way to accomplish what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

eBay API will not allow to create draft listing.

when you call API for creating new listing, API needs all required fields value.

eBay Listing API provide one attribute **PrivateListing**.it will hide your product for selling.

If **PrivateListing** is true, designates the listing as private.customer can't see private listing.

eBay Listing API provide one more attribute **ScheduleTime**.

When you export product in eBay via API you can give **ScheduleTime** as well, eBay will active product for selling based on **ScheduleTime**.

You can make product inactive/draft using this alternative way.

http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/AddItem.html#AddItem

You can refer above link for eBay API.

Comment: This is completely wrong. `PrivateListing` simply hides bidders from being visible on a listing.